# Looping thru multi-dim array

Tags: php

I have the following data structure:

```
results{
        name{
             timestamp( x, y, z)
             timestamp( x, y, z)
             timestamp( x, y, z)
            }
        name{
             timestamp( x, y, z)
             timestamp( x, y, z)
            }
       }
```

(Variable number of names and variable number of timestamps per name)

```
foreach ($results as $name) {
    foreach ($name as $tstamp) {
        printf("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n", $name, $tstamp, $tstamp[0], $tstamp[1], $tstamp[2]);
    }
}
```

I'm getting an array ref for name and tstamp; how do I deference this so I get the intended value?

```
Array,Array,6531,3035,2091
Array,Array,5219,2698,3354
```

Update:
Suppose I have the following data already stored:
    results{
            bob{
                2014-01-01{ 1, 2, 3}
                2014-01-02{ 4, 5, 6}
            }
            steve{
                2014-01-01{ 1, 2, 3}
                2014-01-02{ 4, 5, 6}
            }
     }

How can I print the string "Bob" or "2014-01-01" for example. I have no problem getting the values 1, 2, 3, etc....

Sorry, its been 5+ years since I've touched PHP but I've done this before with an even deeper array.

Comment: $name is an array in the declaration you used

Comment: Which sort of a structure is `timestamp( x, y, z)`. Can you put up a fiddle?

Comment: `$name` and `$tstamp` are arrays, you can't print them. If the number of timestamps are variable, then use another `foreach` to loop through the timestamps and display them? Something like [this](https://eval.in/155177).

Answer (score 1):

Take the 'real' name out of the loop:

```
foreach ($results as $name => $timestamps) {
    foreach (timestamps as $tstamp) {
        printf("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n", $name, $tstamp, $tstamp[0], $tstamp[1], $tstamp[2]);
    }
}
```